# Why is poltergeist firing a change event for an element that isn't on the tested page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, poltergeist

I'm new to poltergeist. I decided to use it for its ability to set cookies, which I have working fine. The problem is that it appears that poltergeist is running all the javascript code in my entire rails project. My feature test is failing because poltergeist is firing an on change event, which triggers an ajax call, for a select tag that doesn't even appear on the page being tested.

The test fails with an:
`ActionController::RoutingError:`
`No route matches [GET] "/users/ajax_sort"`
Which happens, of course, because there is not such route, nor should there be.

It also appears that poltergeist is running at least some of my code twice, evident because a console.log is logging twice.

Any ideas why this is happening? Or how to fix it? Would seeing any of my code help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a jQuery event binding problem. I had it as:
 
`$(document).on('change', '#id_of_select', function()...`
 
Just needed to switch it up to:
`$('#id_of_select).on('change', function()...`